# Ofuscar aplicación de Android, warning Play Console

Tags: java, android, firebase, kotlin

Con esto de los cambios en la consola de Google para los desarrolladores, estoy un poco perdido, cuando he ido a revisar mi aplicación para subirla me ha salido lo siguiente:

> Advertencia Este APK contiene código Java o Kotlin, que puede ser
> ofuscado. Te recomendamos que subas un archivo de desofuscación para
> facilitar el análisis y la depuración de los errores ANR y bloqueos.
> Más información

He estado buscando información sobre la ofuscación y he leído acerca de proguard. Lo he activado pero cuando me voy a Firebase, los nombres de los campos de mi base de datos los ha acortado y no salen con su nombre real. He leído que para esto debo subir el archivo de desofuscación junto con el bundle que subo a la store, pero no encuentro la opción para subir dicho archivo por ningún lado.

Comment: Puedes subir posteriormente tu archivo una vez publicada tu app,agregué imágenes como guía para que sepas como realizarlo.

Comment: He mirado pero aparentemente me dice que ya tiene uno subido...

Comment: Asegura que ese archivo sea para la versión que subiste.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El mensaje es únicamente una advertencia la cual te sugiere ofuscar tu código para que no
sea visible obteniendo el código fuente mediante ingeniería inversa.
Al ser una advertencia podrás subir tu aplicación sin problema.

> Advertencia Este APK contiene código Java o Kotlin, que puede ser
> ofuscado. Te recomendamos que subas un archivo de desofuscación para
> facilitar el análisis y la depuración de los errores ANR y bloqueos.
> Más información

Esto se realiza con la siguiente configuración, principalmente la propiedad  `minifyEnabled true`:

```
android {
    buildTypes {
        release {
            // Enables code shrinking, obfuscation, and optimization for only
            // your project's release build type.
            minifyEnabled true

            // Enables resource shrinking, which is performed by the
            // Android Gradle plugin.
            shrinkResources true

            // Includes the default ProGuard rules files that are packaged with
            // the Android Gradle plugin. To learn more, go to the section about
            // R8 configuration files.
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile(
                    'proguard-android-optimize.txt'),
                    'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Revisa:
[Cómo reducir, ofuscar y optimizar tu app](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code)

Debes [crear tu archivo para ofuscar código](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code#obfuscate) y para subirlo, lo realizas desde la [consola Google Play](https://play.google.com/console/), selecciona la aplicación y desde "Releases overview", puedes revisar en las últimas liberaciones o buscar por versión, y dar clic en la flecha azul:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

dentro en el apartado "App bundles and APKs", da clic en el simbolo de 3 puntos para acceder a la opción "Upload ReTrace mapping file (.txt or .map)", aquí es donde subirás tu archivo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2):

No debería ser necesario que subas ningún archivo. Basta con que actives la minification:

```
minifyEnabled true
proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
```

Tradicionalmente esto activaba proguard pero a partir de la versión 3.4.0 del Android Gradle plugin fue reemplazado por R8. Este es el nuevo code shrinker desarrollado por google y optimizado para android. Tiene dos tareas principales:

- obfuscation: renombra todas las clases, propiedades y métodos con el nombre más corto posible. Aunque esto normalmente es llamado ofuscación, es más apropiado llamarlo minificación porque tu código sigue siendo legible.
- shrinking: elimina todas las clases, propiedades y métodos que aparentemente no se usan.

Si bien R8 es un nuevo compilador, este usa las mismas configuraciones que proguard. Estas configuraciones se encuentran en los archivos definidos en gradle como proguardFiles:

- "proguard-android-optimize.txt": este viene incluido en las android tools y no debes tocarlo.
- "proguard-rules.pro": estas son configuraciones específicas para tu proyecto. Acá puedes hacer cosas como mantener los nombres de las clases que utilizas como modelos de firebase.

No obstante, hay formas mas fáciles de hacerlo. Por ejemplo puedes usar la anotación `@Keep` para que R8 no modifique una clase.

```
@Keep
class Example(
    var foo: String? = null,
    var bar: Int? = null
)
```

Otra alternativa es usar la anotación `@PropertyName` de firebase.

```
class Example(
    @PropertyName("foo") var foo: String? = null,
    @PropertyName("bar") var bar: Int? = null
)
```

De este modo no tendrás problemas cuando se acorten los nombres ya que firebase usará la string de la anotación en vez del nombre de la propiedad.